# Efficiency of insert in string

Tags: c++, string, performance

I'm trying to write this custom addition class for very large integers, bigger than long long. One approach which I'm investigating is keeping the integer as a string and then converting the characters to their int components and then adding each "column". Another approach I'm considering is to split up the string into multiple strings each of which is the size of a long long and then casting it using a string stream into a long long adding and then recombining.

Regardless I came across the fact that addition is done most easily in reverse to allow to the carrying over of digits. This being the case I was wondering the efficiency of the insert method for the string. It seems since a string is an array of chars that all the chars would have to be shifted over one. So it would vary but it would seem the efficiency is O(n) where n is the number of chars in the string.

Is this correct, or is this only with a naive interpretation?

Edit: I now have answer to my question but I was wondering on a related topic which is more efficient, inserting a string into a stream then extracting into an int. Or doing 10^n*char1+10^n-1*char2...etc?

Comment: Don't keep it in a format that is efficient for display, keep it in a format that is efficient for manipulation. You only want to convert it to a string when you want to display it.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. There are already some libraries that implement big integers for you, much more efficient, and already tested!

Comment: Ya I downloaded the gmp library, I just don't know how to get it to work. Plus I figure doing stuff like this will help me learn more about bits and efficiency and other stuff. If you guys think otherwise I'd be happy to move on to any other suggestions.

Comment: @amit good advice for production code, but he may just be doing it for fun.

Comment: @emschorsch consider using a `std::deque` -- it does insert/remove at the front and back in O(1).  Also, storing a multi-precision integer in binary (using full integers for each chunk) will be a lot more efficient and uses the same algorithms.

Comment: @CoryNelson I'm sorry but I've only had one semester of c++. Can you clarify and perhaps elaborate (in a new post maybe) on what you mean by storing integers in binary using full integers as chunks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you are correct. The C++ implementation of String will perform an insert in O(n) time. It treats the string as a character array.

For your numeric implementation, why not store the numbers as arrays of integers and convert to string only for output?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably correct with all real implementations of `std::string`. Under the circumstances, you might want to either store the digits in reverse (though that could be clumsy in other ways) or else use something like an `std::deque<char>`. Better still, use an `std::deque<unsigned long long>`, which will reduce the number of operations involved.

Of course, for real use you usually want to use an existing library rather than rolling your own.

Comment: So is dequeue just the standard library implementation of a list?

Comment: @emschorsch: no. deque provides constant complexity for random access to elements and insertion/deletion at either end (a list would have constant complexity insertion/deletion anywhere, but linear complexity random access to elements).